# XSLT to transform xml in specific format

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Current XML looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<document>
    <attribute>
        <name>Attr1</name>
        <value>Attr1 Value 1</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>Attr2</name>
        <value>Attr 2 Value 1</value>
        <value>Attr 2 Value 2</value>
    </attribute>
</document>
```

I want new xml to look like following ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <document>
        <Attr1>           
            <value>Attr1 Value 1</value>
        </Attr1>
        <Attr2>
            <value>Attr 2 Value 1</value>
            <value>Attr 2 Value 2</value>
        </Attr2>
    </document>
```

I want to use xslt to make this transformation happen ... my xslt does not work

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="/document">
    <document>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/document/attribute">
    <xsl:element name="{name}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="value" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The principal difficulty of this is that you need to create an element with a dynamic name. This is what the `<xsl:element name="{name}">` is for. You can put any xpath expression between the braces. Here we wanted the (hopefully unique) name node of the `/document/attribute` match.

Comment: I used a slightly different way to achieve my solution ... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 
 <xsl:template match="attribute">
    <xsl:element name="{name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>      
    </xsl:element>    
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="name"/> 
</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 0):

I used a different way to handle the above issue ...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="attribute">
        <xsl:element name="{name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>           
        </xsl:element>          
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="name"/>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```